# Tmux usage of if-shell

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I'm trying to get `if-shell` to work. I want to implement the following:

1. Check if vim is running
2. If yes, set `status-left` to one value
3. If no, set `status-left` to another value

I have written this command for step 1:

```bash
is_nvim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?|e)(diff)?$'; echo $?"
```

This echos 0 if vim is active and 1 otherwise. I tested it with `set -g status-left "#($is_nvim)"` and it correctly printed 0 or 1 on the bottom left.

Then I tried using this command (`is_nvim`) with `if-shell`. I tried

```bash
if-shell "$(is_nvim)" "set -g status-left 'a'" "set -g status-left 'b'"
```

and

```bash
if-shell '[ "$(is_nvim)" -eq 1 ]' "set -g status-left 'a'" "set -g status-left 'b'"
```

But both tries did not work, and I'm a bit confused on why.

Does anybody know why `if-shell` does not work, although `is_nvim` returns the correct value?

Comment: what is `$lol`?

Comment: the `if-shell` would run for only once so the `status-left` would not be dynamically updated when you start and exit vim. is this what you expect?

Comment: @pynexj oh damnit. I had a view versions for testing and $lol was one of it. I replaced it with $is_nvim.

Comment: @pynexj Nope, that’s not the behavior I am looking for. Can I put if-shell inside set -g status-left?

Comment: a bit confused. you said `set -g status-left "#($is_nvim)"` is already working for you. so what other effects do you want to get?

Comment: @pynexj So `set -g status-left "#($is_nvim)"` only prints `0` or `1` to the bottom left corner. But I want to print some text depending on this `0` or `1`. So maybe "TMUX" if it`s a `1` and "VIM" if it's a `0`.

Comment: then just update `is_nvim` and change `echo $?` to something like `[ $? = 0 ] && echo foo || echo bar`

Answer (score -1):

To replace variable with its value you need to prefix it with `$`. Use `$($is_nvim)` instead of `$(is_nvim)`.

Comment: I tried `if-shell "$($is_nvim)" "set -g status-left 'a'" "set -g status-left 'b'"` and it didn't work.

Comment: `if-shell "$($is_nvim)"` will not work because it check the exit status only which is always `0`. Use `if-shell '[ "$($is_nvim)" -eq 1 ]'`.